# Push back kinematic object

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

I'm trying to push back an Kinematic object.

Somethink like

```
Vector2 push = new Vector2((other.position.x - transform.position.x), 0).normalized;
push *= 500f;

Rigidbody2D pushRB = other.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
pushRB.velocity = Vector2.zero;

pushRB.AddForce(push);
```

(This code is inside OnTriggerEnter2D)

But for kinematic object. I have tried to use velocity but the objects starts moving constantly, so its not working for me.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Hmm kinematic objects are supposed to stand still. If you want to move them with force turn off kinematic.

Comment: Yeah but I use it for a character and if i disable the kinematic the character starts to act unusually if some object hits hit it falls and stuff like that

Comment: @AVAVT I'm using the unity player platformer script byw